# Копировать файл в память телефона

Tags: android

Пытаюсь реализовать сохранение выбранной в галерее фотографии в память телефона, но получаю ошибку.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private ImageView imgView;
    static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выбрать"), GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                    //Получаем в файл
                    File mPhotoFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage));

                    Log.d("FILEPATH: ", mPhotoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    String fileName = mPhotoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    fileName = fileName.substring(1,fileName.length());
                    Log.d("FILEPATH: ", fileName);

                    //ПОПЫТКА КОПИРОВАТЬ ФАЙЛ
                    try {
                        // отрываем поток для записи
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(mPhotoFile.getAbsolutePath(), MODE_PRIVATE)));
                        // пишем данные
                        bw.write("Содержимое файла");
                        // закрываем поток
                        bw.close();
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Файл записан", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //ПОПЫТКА КОПИРОВАТЬ ФАЙЛ
                }
        }

    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentURI) {
        String result = null;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            if(idx >= 0) {
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Ошибка в строке `BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(mPhotoFile.getAbsolutePath(), MODE_PRIVATE)));`

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File
>   /storage/FC17-10F8/DCIM/Camera/20190322_150749.jpg contains a path
>   separator

Comment: Как вообще копировать картинку из галереи и вставить ее в папку images/myapp в памяти телефона?

Comment: BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(mPhotoFile.getAbsolutePath(), MODE_PRIVATE))); - Вы пытаетесь писать файл в самого себя :)

Comment: А есть пример как правильно это сделать в указанную папку? Этот код, на каком-то сайте нашел

Answer (score 0):

Пример как можно сохранить фото в приватное хранилище приложения:

```
public static void savePhoto(Context mContext, Uri mPhotoUri, String mTargetFileName) throws IOException {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPhotoUri.getPath());

    FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(mTargetFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: А как затем получить ссылку на файл в приватном хранилище?

Comment: bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);  тут ошибку выдает Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы после выборка картинки, она сохранилась в памяти телефона и получить название картинки, чтобы записать в БД. Это необходимо для того, чтобы при открытии списка из БД выводить картинки в recyclerview. А точнее из БД выводить названия и подставлять путь к изображению